# Detect Ubuntu device as a MIDI keyboard/Interface in Windows

Tags: windows, driver, embedded-linux, midi, odroid

I am creating a little experimentation application on my Odroid XU3 with Ubuntu 15.04 Lite.
http://dn.odroid.com/homebackup/201407071058089142.jpg

The device (Odroid) receives midi as input via a keyboard connected via one of the available USB Host ports (this part is OK) and sents some other midi instructions (also via USB, but USB OTG) to the computer to create harmony (this part is not ok).

The use case is :
you play on your midi keyboard some notes, the odroid received them, the embedded application code analyses them, find new notes (midi instructions) and send them to your Windows PC that you can root them to the VST of your choice.

The issue I have is that in order to achieve that, I need the Odroid device to appear as a MIDI keyboard in Windows that people can add the device in their Digital Audio Workstations.

Most of the midi controllers sold on the market have their own drivers but some are class compliant devices.

How can I make Windows detect this Odroid board an a midi keyboard? If I need to write a specific driver for that, from where to start?

Edit : Found g_midi drivers but not usb_f_midi

```
odroid@odroid:/lib/modules/3.10.72-23/kernel/drivers/usb/gadget$ ls -al
total 628   
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 May 23 21:28 .   
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root  4096 May 23 21:27 ..  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 37544 May 23 21:11 g_acm_ms.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 17468 May 23 21:11 g_audio.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24164 May 23 21:11 g_cdc.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 44488 May 23 21:11 g_ether.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 63552 May 23 21:11 g_ffs.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16672 May 23 21:11 g_hid.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 37084 May 23 21:11 g_mass_storage.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 17468 May 23 21:11 g_midi.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 69752 May 23 21:11 g_multi.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28164 May 23 21:11 g_ncm.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 35396 May 23 21:11 g_nokia.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20944 May 23 21:11 g_printer.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9016 May 23 21:11 g_serial.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26628 May 23 21:11 g_webcam.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11408 May 23 21:11 g_zero.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25380 May 23 21:11 gadgetfs.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 45940 May 23 21:11 libcomposite.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15244 May 23 21:11 u_serial.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9972 May 23 21:11 usb_f_acm.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8060 May 23 21:11 usb_f_obex.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6928 May 23 21:11 usb_f_serial.ko  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14584 May 23 21:11 usb_f_ss_lb.ko
```

Second edit : Thanks to CL
Trying the g_midi driver

```
odroid@odroid:/proc/asound$ cat cards
0 [odroidaudio ]: odroid-audio - odroid-audio odroid-audio 
1 [MPK225 ]: USB-Audio - MPK225 Akai MPK225 at usb-12110000.usb-1.2, full speed 
2 [K61 ]: USB-Audio - Keystation 61 M-Audio Keystation 61 at usb-12110000.usb-1.3, full speed.

$ modprobe g_midi in_ports=1 out_ports=1
```

Error :

```
modprobe : ERROR : could not insert 'g_midi' : Device Or Ressource busy.
```

Same error with other ports (3,4, etc)

When removing the Midi keyboards :

```
odroid@odroid:/proc/asound$ cat cards
0 [odroidaudio ]: odroid-audio - odroid-audio odroid-audio 

$ modprobe g_midi in_ports=1 out_ports=1
```

same error :

```
modprobe : ERROR : could not insert 'g_midi' : Device Or Ressource busy.
```

Comment: Linux has a gadget driver for USB MIDI (`usb_f_midi.ko`), but I don't know if it is enabled in your Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it the same as http://blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=linux-kernel:usb-gadget:midi ?

Comment: `g_midi` is an older version. But you first need a kernel that actually has it enabled.

Comment: Thanks CL. I will try this first with my actual kernel to see if it's enabled.

Comment: Edited the post with some drivers found.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 should use kernel 3.19. Is that the kernel you're actually running (`uname -r`)?

Comment: It's using Kernel 3.10 81-33. It's the kernel used by default for Ubuntu 15.04 Lite with the distributed images from HardKernel (Odroid XU3 Lite)      http://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=95&t=13353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load the `g_midi` module:

```
$ modprobe g_midi in_ports=1 out_ports=1
```

(1 and 1 are the defaults.)

This will create a class-compliant USB MIDI interface, which is visible on the Odroid like a normal sound card:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [whatever       ]: ...
 1 [gmidi          ]: MIDI Gadget - g_midi
                      MIDI Gadget
```

... and can be accessed with the normal Linux MIDI APIs.

Comment: Edited my first post. Device Or Ressource busy error

Comment: I don't know the limitations of the the XU3's OTG controller. Do `g_serial` or `g_ether` work?

Comment: modprobe g_serial doesn't return any error whereas modprobe g_ether returns : No such device. What I don't understand is how to target the OTG port (Odroid as Slave) and not the USB host ports (used as host input for the keyboards, odroid as Master)

Comment: After I typed modprobe g_serial and connect the Windows PC via USB/USB OTG to the Odroid, it does appear as Windows is trying to install the driver. Gadget Serial v2.4 can be found in Unknown Devices in Windows

Comment: On the properties of the device, it's written Port #0003 Hub #0001 (On Windows)

Comment: So the OTG mechanism itself works; this busy error is a problem with the `g_midi` driver. Try asking on the Odroid forum.

Comment: Really appreciated your help thanks. I will update this thread when/if I have an answer on their side.